# How to unlock one entity under JPA

Tags: jpa

all.

I was writting a program using pure JPA , whose provider was hibernate, and the underlying database was Azure SQL DB. This program will run under a distributed environment, many copy of it will be running on different servers.

I need go some procedure like that (for ex-):
  1, lock a specified student entity, 
  2, check the status of clas entity, if the status was 1,then continue, else, try to lock this class entity , untile get the lock of this class 
  3, check the status of the status  ( maybe modified by other thread from the another server due to distributed environment), if still not 1, then do something, modified the status to 1,
  4,  unlock  this class entity 
  5, do other things ( still hold the lock over present student entity)

i get lock by the following code seg:

```
    Map<String,Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("javax.persistence.lock.timeout", 0);
    return this.getEntityManager().find( cls, id,  LockModeType.PESSIMISTIC_WRITE,map);
```

but, i dont know how to realease the lock at step 4,
Are there any method to just realse the lock over a entity ,and remained other locks?

Thanks a lot, any advice will be appropriated.

Answer (score 6):

You have to set the lock mode to none

```
  em.lock(myEntity, LockModeType.NONE);
```

See http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/lock

Comment: Some databases (e.g. MySQL) always hold a lock until the end of the current transaction. Setting the lock to `NONE` has no effect.

Comment: Just a small question: In general that means unlocking is not needed usually. So everything is unlocked at the end of a transaction right?

Comment: everything is unlocked at the end of the transaction :)